# Running a forever TCP server in a Callback function of a Tkinter button Python

Tags: python, tcpserver

I am a newbie to Python and I am working with my bachelor project.
Recently, I have succesfully implemented a always-run TCP server in Python with *socketserver*. This server can run forever and wait for the request from cli Below is my code:

```
import SocketServer
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper()

#start the TCP server and keep it run forever until click stop button
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Rightnow, I am starting to work with GUI (ie. Tkinter) to create a Dialog board. I created a dialog box with a button OK on it. I would like to start the always-run TCP server only when the user click OK button. Below is my code for the dialog box:

```
import tkinter
master = tkinter.Tk()
e = tkinter.Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def callback():
      print (e.get()) # This is the text you may want to use later
      master.destroy()

b = tkinter.Button(master, text ="OK", width = 10, command = callback) 
b.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

I have tried to put the start server code (below) into the *Callback* function of the button, but the server can only run one time and then be executed.

```
 #start the TCP server and keep it run forever until click stop button
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Anyone can help me, how to start the server after click the button and keep the server run forever?

Thank you very much